# Simplicial approximation theorem and related stuff

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

I would like to ask for a list of references that explain the simplicial approximation theorem, barycentric subdivisions and Kan $Ex^{\infty}$ functor in details, fully exploiting the language of simplicial sets where needed (which is not what most of the books on algebraic topology do).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Curtis's notes Simplicial Homotopy Theory (Advances in Math, 1971) are the place where I first saw this sort of discussion.

Comment: Goerss-Jardine *Simplicial homotopy theory* might be of assistance (I do not know if the explicitely treat simplicial approximation though)